# Hierarchy creation using Oracle functions

Tags: oracle, plsql, hierarchical-data

Is it possible to create a hierarchy for dimensions using oracle functions?

Please see an example below for an organisational level hierarchy.

```
+-----+------+---------+
| EMP | LEAD | MANAGER |
+-----+------+---------+
| E1  | L1   | M1      |
| E3  | L3   | M1      |
| E2  | L2   | M1      |
+-----+------+---------+
```

But the final representation of data should be like(*sample*) :

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| EMP | LVL_1_ID | LVL_2_ID | LVL_3_ID |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| M1  |          |          | M1       |
| L1  |          | L1       | M1       |
| L2  |          | L2       | M1       |
| E1  | E1       | L1       | M1       |
| E2  | E2       | L2       | M1       |
| E3  | E3       | L3       | M1       |
| L3  |          | L3       | M1       |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
```

EMP_ID column will have the entries for all the employees(Leads and Managers included).

Code :

```
    SELECT employee AS emp_id,
    employee AS Level_1_id,
    LEAD AS level_2_id,
    Manager AS Level_3_id
    FROM temp_emp
    UNION
    SELECT LEAD AS emp_id,
    NULL AS Level_1_id,
    LEAD AS level_2_id,
    Manager AS Level_3_id
    FROM temp_emp
    UNION
    SELECT manager AS emp_id,
    NULL AS Level_1_id,
    NULL AS level_2_id,
    Manager AS Level_3_id
    FROM temp_emp ;
```

Based on the comments I have tried the 'Connect By' clause on the following data set :

```
+-----+---------+
| EMP | MANAGER |
+-----+---------+
| E1  | L1      |
| E2  | L1      |
| E3  | L2      |
| L1  | M1      |
| L2  | M1      |
| M1  |         |
+-----+---------+
```

To get the following result :

```
 +-----+----------+----------+-----------+
 | EMP | LVL_1_ID | LVL_2_ID | LVL_3_ID  |
 +-----+----------+----------+-----------+
 | M1   |          |          |M1        |
 | L1   |          |L1        |          |
 | L2   |          |L2        |          |
 | E1   |E1        |          |          |
 | E2   |E2        |          |          |
 | E3   |E3        |          |          |
 +-----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Code used to get this (Still not the required answer ) :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT EMP AS CH,EMP AS emp,LEVEL AS LVL
FROM TEMP_EMP
START WITH MANAGER IS NULL
CONNECT BY  PRIOR EMP = MANAGER)
PIVOT (MAX(CH) FOR (LVL) IN ('3' AS LVL_1_ID,'2' AS LVL_2_ID,'1' AS  LVL_3_ID));
```

Expected Result :

```
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| EMP | LVL_1_ID | LVL_2_ID | LVL_3_ID |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
| M1  |          |          | M1       |
| L1  |          | L1       | M1       |
| L2  |          | L2       | M1       |
| E1  | E1       | L1       | M1       |
| E2  | E2       | L1       | M1       |
| E3  | E3       | L2       | M1       |
+-----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: use a hierarchy select by including `connect by`.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a minimal example of the DDL statements for the tables and the sample data and what you have tried to get the result. Please do **not** post links to images.

Comment: Why don't you have rows in the final result set for C, X and Y? And have you looked at the examples [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332), which are based on employee-manager relationships?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand quite what you're trying to do, or why you're mixing numbers, letters and symbols. What results *do* you expect from your updated sample data?

Comment: @AlexPoole : Edits made for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will give the required answer :

```
select ch AS EMP,lvl,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (path, '[^///]+', 1, 3)   as lvl1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (path, '[^///]+', 1, 2)   as lvl2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (path, '[^///]+', 1, 1)   as lvl3
from (
SELECT EMP AS CH,manager as par,level as lvl,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(EMP , '///') as path
FROM TEMP_EMP
START WITH MANAGER IS NULL
CONNECT BY  PRIOR EMP = MANAGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle **connect by** does this and it has the pseudo column **level** to help you keep track if where in the hierarchy you are

[Hierarchical Queries - Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

An excellent explanation:  http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to avoid UNION,

```
select ch AS EMP,lvl,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (path, '[^///]+', 1, 3)   as lvl1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (path, '[^///]+', 1, 2)   as lvl2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR (path, '[^///]+', 1, 1)   as lvl3
from (
SELECT EMP AS CH,manager as par,level as lvl,
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(EMP , '///') as path
FROM (select emp,lead(emp,1,NULL) over(partition by r order by lvls) manager from (  
select val emp,lvls,r from (
select R,lvls,val from (
SELECT emp,lead,manager,row_number()over(order by emp) r FROM TEMP_EMP2)   unpivot(val for lvls in (emp as '1', lead as '2',manager as '3') ))))
START WITH MANAGER IS NULL
CONNECT BY  PRIOR EMP = MANAGER);
```